# Deserialization kotlin data class android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have simple class

```
data class UserInfo(val id:String, val name:String, val email:String) : Serializable
{
}
```

I serialize it to string

```
(userInfo as Serializable).toString()
```

How can I deserialize it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read documentation for Serializable https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html and Object.toString() https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

You did not serialize an object.

You can use ByteArrayOutputStream to serialize object into it.